Determine the real numbers a and b for which the relation $a+b+246=22*(\sqrt{a+1024}+\sqrt{b-1020})$ occurs
the problem
Determine the real numbers a and b for which the relation $a+b+246=22*(\sqrt{a+1024}+\sqrt{b-1020})$ occurs
my idea
The problem would have been so easy if the numbers would be rational... i tried solving it using rational numbers and got some solutions: (a,b)=(-4,2),(-4, -24),(-18,2),(-18,-24),(2,-4),(-24,-4),(2,-18),(-24,-18)
Hope someone can help me solve it with real numbers, because I have absolutely no idea! Thanks!

Sorry, for $a=-4,b=2$ the equation is not true: $(a+b+246)=244$, while the right hand side is not a real number, because $b-1020=-1018$ is negative. Same for all other solutions.

@DietrichBurde somehow I found a really beautiful way. Mind checking this? Is this process valid?

@Gwen It's correct , I got the same result using a different way (that's probably way too long)

@ράτ thanks for the verification :)

$$a+b+246=22(\sqrt{a+1024}+\sqrt{b-1020})$$
$$\implies (\sqrt{a+1024})^2-22\sqrt{a+1024}+121-(1024+121)+(\sqrt{b-1020})^2-22\sqrt{b-1020}+121 +(1020-121)+246=0$$
Magically, $246$ cancels out.
$$(\sqrt{a+1024}-11)^2+(\sqrt{b-1020}-11)^2=0$$
This occurs only if
$$\sqrt{a+1024}=11\implies a=-903$$
$$\sqrt{b-1020}=11\implies b=1141$$

Gwen, congratulations ! I like your answer so much !

Thank you @Angelo :)
